# AWS Cloudformation Error: SecurityGroup 'typeNameList' Member must satisfy constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

**Cloud Formation AWS Security Problem**

Using AWS CloudFormation YAML to create resource stack with EC2, etc and RDS database. Have specific issue with reference Member constraint on SecurityGroup.

Member must satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 204, Member must have length greater than or equal to 10. What is this error specifically referring to to fix the member constraint? I've looked carefully and don't see what I have in error.

**Template Error**

Member must satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 204, Member must have length greater than or equal to 10

CloudFormation stack error is referencing SecurityGroup at 'typeNameList', but I not exactly sure where this 'typeNameList' is in error in my script.

**CloudFormation Script Error Message**

```
1 validation error detected: Value '[AWS::EC2::RouteTable, 
AWS::S3::BucketPolicy, AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener,
 AWS::EC2::InternetGateway, AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup,
 AWS::EC2::Subnet, AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id, AWS::RDS::DBInstance,
 AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer, AWS::EC2::VPC,
 AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation,
 AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment, AWS::EC2::Route, AWS::S3::Bucket,
 AWS::EC2::Instance, AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup]' at 'typeNameList'
 failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member
 must have length less than or equal to 204, Member must have length
 greater than or equal to 10, Member must satisfy regular expression
 pattern: [A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}
(::MODULE){0,1}]
```

**CloudFormation Script code**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  DBInstance:
    Default: DBInstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String

  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '20'
    MaxValue: '65536'

  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Description: Master username for the RDS instance
    Default: admin

  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    Description: Master password for the RDS instance
    Default: password

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC Internet Gateway

  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnet 1

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet 1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnet 2

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet 2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Route Table

  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Private Route Table

  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable

  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable

  EC2Instance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      KeyName: EC2Instance1
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          #echo "<h1>Hello from Region us-east-2b</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html

  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

  ELBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ELB Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/24

  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: Security group egress
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
          IpProtocol: "-1"

  EC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group
      DependsOn: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        SourceSecurityGroupId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - ELBSecurityGroup
          - GroupId
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'myBucketV5'

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      KeyName: S3BucketPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:*'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/@matthew'

  EC2TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 15
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Name: EC2TargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
        Value: '20'
      Targets:
      - Id: !Ref EC2Instance1
        Port: 80
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3

  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref EC2TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - !Ref PublicSubnet1
      - !Ref PublicSubnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt ELBSecurityGroup.GroupId

  MyRDS:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstance
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
      KeyName: MyRDS

Outputs:
  EC2InstanceId:
    Description: InstanceId of EC2 instance
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance1

  S3BucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket

  DBInstanceId:
    Description: DBInstanceIdentifier of RDS instance
    Value: !Ref DBInstance
```

Comment: This has the feel of an unterminated string. You could try running `cf-lint` to see if it gives any more information. But another solution is to deploy the stack incrementally, a few resources at a time, to identify which is malformed. I also strongly recommend using explicit string quoting, rather than relying on YAML implied strings.

Comment: question; what is the approach to run cf-lint? I installed cfn-lint. Ran: cfn-lint -t aws-platform.design.yaml  (file local same director) Error:::              
2023-11-13 08:43:01,368 - cfnlint.decode.decode - ERROR - Template file not found: aws-platform.design.yaml
but error: E0000 Template file not found: aws-platform.design.yaml
aws-platform.design.yaml:1:1

Comment: Might not be related but you have `S3Bucket` defined twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 186

```
SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
```

Should be

```
SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
```

Moreover, you have two "S3Bucket" declarations, one in line 172 second one in line 212

Answer (score 0):

Based on the regex in the error the issue is with the type names (lines such as `Type: AWS::EC2::VPC`). If you search for lines starting `Type: 'AWS` remove the the single quotes(`'`) at the start and end of the type should fix it.